# Copy int column to another column with positive values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have column a with different int values (positives and negative) i would like to copy values from Column A to B and if a value is negative convert to positive
the following didn't work

```
UPDATE myTable SET B = ABS(A);
```

Thank you

Comment: Don't store values computed from other columns. Either create a view, or have a _computed column_.

Comment: What "didn't work" means?!

Comment: Sample data would do the work!

Comment: when i use UPDATE myTable SET B = ABS(A); then there is nothing copied, the new column remains 0's

Comment: `ABS(−2147483648)`?

Comment: Do you `commit` your update?

Comment: Yes i did commit, is it a bug in SQL 2012? or should i reinstall SQL MS
Any way picklerick solution did the trick, thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TRY

```
 UPDATE myTable SET B = case when A < 0 then -A else A end
```

Comment: This looks logically correct, but it doesn't explain why the OP's much simpler update statement is not working.  Maybe we should wait for feedback before answering?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen ABS didn't work cause it return a numeric_expression i guess, so, i thiught this was the answer he was looking for

Comment: Thank you, this one works
i use ABS alot, don't understand why it doens't in this case

Comment: While this does fix the problem it still isn't the best approach because storing computed values it not ideal. Using a computed column is a much better approach.

Comment: Well, i have my reasons to use this approach, and i'm not asking for best practice, this is one time update for data that will never change again

Comment: @SeanLange maybe he just need to do a simple update, not to rewrite his table

Comment: It will never change again...until the next time it changes again. ;) Regardless I am glad you found a solution.

Comment: I can't imagine any situations where this would work and `ABS()` would not work.  If anyone can think of one, please explain!

Comment: @GordonLinoff  I think that's becouse ABS() return a  numeric_expression and the column is int, so if you want to store ABS() output you have to cast it. i think that also  convert(int,ABS(A)) will work

Comment: @picklerick . . . The only possible error that I can imagine would be an out-of-range error, and the `case` expression would generate the same error:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=25cbde47a03c93fd8c33ac4d3b9628fc

Answer (score 1):

Just add a computed column instead:

```
alter table t add b as (abs(a));
```

That way, the value of `b` is computed when accessed, so you don't have to worry that it gets out-of-synch with `a`.

Your code should work, assuming that `a` is a numeric type and `b` is defined in the table.